# Skipping backward in a file in java

Tags: java, fileinputstream

I'm using `FileInputStream` in Java to parse an input file, and I want to be able to skip backwards within that file. I have had mixed results, and according to the Javadocs this is not possible, though it has worked in other parts of the program.
Currently I am getting an:

> 'Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Invalid argument'

I believe `RandomAccessFile` yields the same problem. Any tips that would make this possible?

**EDIT:**
An example of where the error is occurring:

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(inputfile);
file.read(check,0,6);
file.skip(-6);
```

Comment: And what code is causing the problem? Could we see a small code snippet?

Comment: FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(inputfile); file.read(check,0,6);
file.skip(-6);

Comment: Skipping backwards is not guaranteed to work. The javadoc clearly indicates it will be attempted but may not be supported: `If n is negative, the method will try to skip backwards.`  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#skip-long-

Comment: Are all of your reads relatively small like the given example? Perhaps a better choice would be to wrap with a BufferedInputStream and use mark/reset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you [get the FileChannel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#getChannel--) associated with the FileInputStream you can set the [position](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#position-long-) on the channel, which will affect the next read from the stream.

Similarly, if you use a [RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html), you can [seek](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#seek-long-) to a desired position in file.